# how can i change position of inputs in high charts high-stock?

Tags: javascript, css, input, charts, highcharts

This is default style of my chart in highcharts :
I want to change position of inputs, charts that I use are from https://www.highcharts.com/ site , 
i want to change **from input** from **left to right** and **to input** from **right to left** with from and to texts
[image: 1]

**I want to be like this image :**
[image: 2]

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to change in regular Highcharts API options, but making some changes in core code does the job.

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h4rx83m0/1/)

At **Highcharts.RangeSelector.prototype.render** we need to switch sequence of triggering **rangeSelector.drawInput** functions:

```
if (inputEnabled !== false) {
  rangeSelector.div = div = createElement('div', null, {
    position: 'relative',
    height: 0,
    zIndex: inputsZIndex
  });

  container.parentNode.insertBefore(div, container);

  // Create the group to keep the inputs
  rangeSelector.inputGroup = inputGroup =
    renderer.g('input-group').add(group);
  inputGroup.offset = 0;

  rangeSelector.drawInput('max');
  rangeSelector.drawInput('min');

}
```

In **Highcharts.RangeSelector.prototype.drawInput** I made some styling/creating changes here:

```
// Create an SVG label that shows updated date ranges and and records
// click events that bring in the HTML input.
this[name + 'DateBox'] = dateBox = renderer.label('', inputGroup.offset)
  .addClass('highcharts-range-input')
  .attr({
    padding: 2,
    width: options.inputBoxWidth || 90,
    height: options.inputBoxHeight || 17,
    'text-align': 'center'
  })
  .on('click', function() {
    // If it is already focused, the onfocus event doesn't fire
    // (#3713)
    rangeSelector.showInput(name);
    rangeSelector[name + 'Input'].focus();
  });
// Create the text label
this[name + 'Label'] = label = renderer.label(
    lang[isMin ? 'rangeSelectorFrom' : 'rangeSelectorTo'],
    this.inputGroup.offset
  )
  .addClass('highcharts-range-label')
  .attr({
    padding: 2,
    paddingLeft: 100
  })
  .add(inputGroup);

inputGroup.offset += label.width - 85;
```

Comment: Thank You `@Sebastian Wedzel` , Your Solution Worked!